# CSS excluído ainda está afetando o arquivo HTML

Tags: html, css, cache

Eu estava criando um site básico no HTML, então resolvi mexer um pouco com CSS para organizar onde cada coisa do site iria ficar usando as `divs`, então criei um arquivo separado para mexer no CSS. No começo estava tudo certo, mas depois de um tempo as alterações que eu fazia no arquivo CSS não estavam mais afetando o arquivo HTML, então tentei fazer umas alterações mais drásticas pra confirmar isso. Mudei a cor no CSS e como pensei isso não afetou o arquivo HTML, então resolvi excluir o arquivo CSS, e o site HTML continuou com as alterações antigas mesmo eu tendo excluído o arquivo CSS.

Queria saber porque isso acontece?

Site em HTML:

```
 <html>
<head>
    <title>Minha Listai</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/paginaInicial.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div1">
        <h1>Minha Listai</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="div2">
        <input type="button" name="btLogar" value="Logar">
        <input type="button" name="brDeslogar" value="Deslogar">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Site no Google Chrome:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como podem ver não tem nenhum arquivo CSS e mesmo assim o site está como se tivesse um, e sim já atualizei a página diversas vezes e tenho certeza que o arquivo HTML está se a uma pasta vazia.

Comment: Isso se chama cache. O navegador guarda uma versão do seu arquivo em memória para não ter que transferí-lo toda vez através da requisição HTTP. Isso faz com que seu site seja carregado mais rápido. Limpe o cache do navegador e seu problema estará resolvido.

Comment: Se eu ficar usando o modo anônimo o google para de salvar meu site no cache ?

Comment: No modo anônimo o cache não será salvo, de fato. Este Google de que fala seria o Google Chrome?

Comment: Sim é do Google Chorme que estou falando

Comment: O problema foi resolvido ao limpar o cache ou acessar a página em modo anônimo?

Comment: Foi, obrigado...